# Как сделать антиспам для бота? Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['nospam']
def antispam(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Continue")
    тут будет код
```

Нужно чтобы пользователь после этого **в течении 30 сек** пишет что-то бот ответить "Please wait {время который надо ждать} seconds"